# Django Rest Framework - PermissionDenied raises 500 status code

Tags: django, rest, exception, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

i am working with django rest framework and want to raise a PermissionDenied exception and return a 403 response to user:

```
raise PermissionDenied("Custom exception message")
```

But it returns a 500 status code...

Can anybody explain?

thanks!

Comment: `raise PermissionDenied("Custom exception message")` returns 403 by default. If you are getting 500 there is a programming error. You have a mistake somewhere else in your code, response with 500 is probably returned even before control reaches raise PermissionDenied

Comment: i am raising the exception in my middleware which inherits from RemoteUserMiddleware... could this be the reasonß

Comment: where are you importing PermissionDenied from? both django and rest_framework has PermissionDenied

Comment: from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied
can you refer to it?

Comment: sorry doesn't matter where you import from, syntax for raising it almost the same. There must be some other error in your code. Try printing something just before raising it to make sure actually that is returning a 500 code

Comment: it actually mattered! i imported it from django and viola, it works as expected and return correct 403

Comment: Drf also gives code 403, I use it always.

Comment: right, @Creativecrypter I'm facing the same issue as you mentioned. If you use PermissionDenied from django.core.exceptions then it works perfectly but if you use from rest_framework then it gives 500 inside a middleware.